# TableDef immediately out of scope

Tags: vba, ms-access

For some reason I can't seem to get a TableDef to stick around after assignment:

```
Sub TDefOutOfScope(tblName As String)

Dim tDef As TableDef
Dim x As Integer

Set tDef = CurrentDb.TableDefs(tblName) ' object set ok here, fields visible in watch window
For x = 0 To tDef.Fields.Count - 1 ' error 3420
   ' doing stuff
Next x

End Sub
```

Error on the for-loop line;

> Error 3420: Object invalid or no longer set

This works OK:

```
For x = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs(tblName).Fields.Count - 1
```

Using Access in Office 365, same issue in all (unrelated) DBs I've tried.

Comment: A common issue, see the duplicate for an explanation, use `Dim db As DAO.Database` `Set db = CurrentDb` `Set tdef = db.TableDefs(tblName)`